Apache forwards to wrong port
I have different subdomains which I want to end up to proxy to different ports

kibana.featurename.subdomain.mydomain.com should be forwarded to port 5601
pma.featurename.subdomain.mydomain.com should be forwarded to port 8090
featurename.subdomain.mydomain.com should be forwarded tot port 8000

Because of this I've created the following config in apache.
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName kibana.featurename.subdomain.mydomain.com

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:5601/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5601/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/featurename-kibana-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/featurename-kibana-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName pma.featurename.subdomain.mydomain.com

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8090/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8090/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/featurename-pma-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/featurename-pma-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName featurename.subdomain.mydomain.com

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8000/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/featurename-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/featurename-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

Now all traffic on those domains are being proxied to port 5601. subdomained both in browser as via curl:

http://kibana.featurename.subdomain.mydomain.com (correctly loads kibana at port 5601)
http://pma.featurename.subdomain.mydomain.com (opens kibana at port 5601, instad of the application on port 8090)
http://featurename.subdomain.mydomain.com (opens kibana at port 5601, instad of the application on port 8000)

To solve this issue, I've tried the following:

Adding unique ServerAlias to each config: no effect
Change the order of the vhosts: it's now all proxied to another (but all the same) port


Are you sure it isn't browser issue? Check with curl to all three domains that replies are really the same. Also, what's in logs, especially general server error log and logs of each of these involved virtualhosts?

Have to make sure that the ServerName and ServerAlias directives in each <VirtualHost> block are correct and distinct.
For example:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName kibana.featurename.subdomain.mydomain.com

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:5601/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5601/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName pma.featurename.subdomain.mydomain.com

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8090/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8090/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName featurename.subdomain.mydomain.com

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8000/
</VirtualHost>

Also, make sure mod_proxy and mod_proxy_http are enabled.
sudo a2enmod proxy
sudo a2enmod proxy_http

If that doesn't fix it, check for conflicting configurations or duplicate ServerName entries, or some ServerAlias in other configuration files.
Restart apache after making configuration changes to confirm.

Thanks for your response. This is what ChatGPT told me as well. But as you can see the ServerName values are unique. Both mods are enabled, otherwise it wouldn't work at all. No other vhosts are active on this machine

Make sure it isn't included in conf-enabled/.conf  and/or sites-enabled/.conf . Set LogLevel debug in your apache config and then restart it like this sudo journalctl -u apache2 -f -o verbose to find where the problem is.
